# Unable to install the latest version of Gitlab

Tags: git, bash, curl, gitlab

This question is not about code, but the installation of Gitlab.

I am trying to install Gitlab for few days now without success.
Indeed, some times ago, they proposed the method with `wget` that worked very well, but since we must use the method with `Curl`, it is impossible to go further than the download.

On Ubuntu 14.04 machine, the following command works :

```
curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
```

But with the next command, it appears [0% pending] and nothing happens again.

```
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

Have you ever faced this problem since the 7.10.4 version of Gitlab or do you know a way to solve this problem. Installation from the source is for me something very difficult to implement.

Here is the full error :

```
Err packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu trusty/main gitlab-ce amd64 7.10.4~omnibus.1-1 Operation too slow.
Less than 10 bytes/sec transferred the last 120 seconds
E: Impossible de récupérer packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/pool/trusty/main/g/…
Operation too slow. Less than 10 bytes/sec transferred the last 120 seconds
```

When I do `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list`, I have this result :

```
deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ trusty main
```

And [this page](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/) doesn't exists. Is this the problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't believe it. Problem starts again today ...

I tried to update to the most recent version of Gitlab, and I was returned a fatal error.

### Don't forget to make a backup of your configuration :

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

It is available at `/var/opt/gitlab/backups/`

---

I therefore had to uninstall Gitlab :

```
sudo gitlab-ctl uninstall
```

Then **reinstall**. Here is the **methodology** :

1. **If it is your first Gitlab installation** else start at step 2:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-server ca-certificates postfix
   ```
2. Then, (I'm working with Ubuntu 14.04), go [here](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce), and select the package you want, and do (I have chosen the following, because it is the most recent) :

   ```
   wget https://downloads-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu-14.04/gitlab-ce_8.3.2-ce.0_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Then call `dpkg`  :

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i gitlab-ce_8.3.2-ce.0_amd64.deb
   ```
4. Then :

   ```
   sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
   ```
5. After this, you have to restore your backup and reconfigure your environment

Reminders :

```
Username: root 
Password: 5iveL!fe
```

Comment: It works for me. Still don't know why failed on my Ubuntu14 server

Answer (score 0):

You use apt-get which does not look for your `curl` downloaded package.
Find the right locatio of teh file, add it to the `apt-get` database and then execute:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

More information and detailed steps can be found [here](http://caseyscarborough.com/blog/2013/09/22/installing-gitlab-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/)

Comment: Sure, there is a very detailed explanation on how to do it.

Comment: I don't understand... that link is just to the source install which doesn't use the dpkg.  I'm having the same problem where `apt-get install gitlab-ce` just hangs at 0% forever.